# Visual Studio Code Debugger not being able to import modules from my Conda environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to use the VS Code Python debugger with my Conda environment. If I run my code through the terminal or pressing the play button, it runs correctly. However, if I try to debug it, when I import an external module like pandas or numpy, I get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

The environment is selected with the interpreter, and I've tried several launch.json configurations, but nothing seems to work. I've also check and pandas is correctly installed in the environment, in fact, I can import it if I run it through the terminal. Anybody knows what's going on? I'm using VS Code on Windows 10 and Anaconda. I've also tried PyCharm debugger and I run in the same problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "_and I've tried several launch.json configurations, but nothing seems to work_" show them.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps to create a new *launch.json* on the *Run and Debug* panel, keeping the default configuration.

[image]

Use the ***green button*** in the **Run and Debug** panel to start debugging the program.

[image]

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging